# How to scale x-axis in matplotlib with unequal gaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

I have to following table:

[image: enter link description here]

and I create the following graph with this code:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIFiT.png):

```
plt.plot(new[201], label='201')
plt.genend()
plt.show()
```

graph:

[image: enter link description here]

how can I scale the x-axis NOT to be with equal gaps?

for example, if I use the same data in excel I get this graph:

[image: enter link description here]

so how can I make the graph in python to be like in excel ?

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/error messages. Post the formatted text directly here on SO. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71412234/edit). As for the question - you probably plot non-numerical data. Make sure that the plotted columns are of dtype float.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have your data as strings. Most likely the x-axis is occupied by string values. You have not provided the data, so I have no idea what new[201] looks like. However, I guess all you need is to cast it to float with something like:

```
new[201].astype(np.float)
```

Of course, this is for numpy array. In case your data have a different format, check the specific way to cast it from string to float.

Comment: @RvN I am glad I have helped. If the solution worked, please accept it by pressing the button to the left of the answer. Comments should be used only for further clarification on Stack Overflow.